# ubuntu dual boot problem

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, lenovo, bios

I recently bought a new laptop (z50 20354). it came with win 8.1 pre installed, i decided to dual boot it with ubuntu(14.04). i had to change my bios settings and did the following:

- changed OS optimization to other OS
- changed boot mode and priority to legacy

after this i successfully installed ubuntu and after some time when i tried to start win 8.1 again, it gave me the following error:

```
File:\Boot\BCD
Status:0xC000000e
Info:The Boot configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

i figured it would have something to do with BIOS settings so after some time i figured out Bootmode and Priority were the problem, with these two set to default, i was able to start win8.1 again but this time the screen did not come in which i could chose between ubuntu or win8.1 so only win8.1 is working now and if i have to start ubuntu i have to change BIOS settings again.

Is there any way i can chose between Operating Syatems without going to BIOS screen everytime ?

I hope i was able to explain my problem correctly, pls ignore any mistakes (english is not my native language).

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall Ubuntu, but without changing to Legacy mode in the BIOS. Ubuntu supports EFI perfectly. I'm pretty sure your problem is that the EFI version of Windows 8 was installed, while you installed the BIOS/Legacy version of Ubuntu.

Try to boot into the legacy part of Windows when it is EFI won't work. You could also try this, in case you don't want to reinstall Ubuntu. Start up Ubuntu and open a terminal window. Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

This might work, but I think the first method will work a lot better.

Comment: is there anyway to uninstall ubuntu without a windows cd ?

Comment: Not uninstall, reinstall. Put the Ubuntu installation media in and boot from it, but make sure your BIOS settings are not Legacy.

Comment: that did not work , if the BIOS settings are not legacy, my laptop doesnt recognise the usb and just loads up windows 8.1. i deleted the partition of ubuntu but now i am having trouble removing the boot loader. i know i need to repair windows 8.1 and install the bootloadder but i dont know how. although since ubuntu's bootloader was never starting in EFI, i do not have a problem and windows 8.1 is working correctly

Comment: You can remove Ubuntu's old bootloader, which may make another reinstall successful, but it's a little tricky. In Windows, open Control Panel (not PC Settings). Go into Administrative Tools, then click Computer Management. From here, click Disk Management, under Storage in the sidebar. Once the window comes up, select the very first partition listed, right click it and select Change Drive Letter and Paths. Assign it a letter from this window, the go into it from Explorer (This Computer). Delete everything labeled Ubuntu inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the BIOS back to legacy and boot back into Ubuntu you could attempt to reinstall the bootloader specifying UEFI rather than BIOS. Using something similar to:

`grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi`

I've only ever manually installed grub when using Arch but I think it's relatively the same process under Ubuntu.